How to construct a line that divides a given triangle into two tiles of equal area
I was interested in a problem of consructing a line that passes throгgh a given point on a triangle and divides it into to polygond of equal area. I solved it (?) using the physical properties of a centroid of a triangle, however I am not sure that I didn't make any mistakes throughout the argument. I would really appreciate any corrections or maybe even another way of solving it. Here is my proof:
Claim: Any line that passes through the centroid of a triangle divides it into two pieces of equal area
Proof:
I started off by assuming a triangular prism $ABCA_1B_1C_1$ where $ABC$ and $A_1B_1C_1$ are copies of a triangle that we want to divide, also let $O$ be the centroid of a triangle $ABC$, let it be projected on a triangle $A_1B_1C_1$ and call the resulting point $O_1$ Picture1 . Now assume that there is a cone, that doesn't cross our prism and whose apex lies on a point $O_1$ Picture2. Finally assume that the prism $ABCA_1B_1C_1$ has mass and a uniform density. Now to the proof intself. Since the centroid of a triangle is also its center of mass, the prism will balance on the apex of a cone. So for a randomly chosen section $MNM_1N_1$ of a prism (such that $MN\in ABC$ and $M_1N_1\in A_1B_1C_1$, $MN$ passes through $O$ and $M_1N_1$ through $O_1$) Picture3, it must divide the prism into two parts of equal mass, because otherwise the prism wouldn't stay balanced and instead would deviate to the side with a larger mass. Since the masses of the two tilings are the same, then so are their volumes, because $V=m\cdot d $, where $m$ is mass and $d$ is the (uniform) density. But also, the volume of both tilings can be evaluated from a general formula for prisms, namely $V=B \cdot h$, where $B$ is the area of a base, and $h$ is the height of a prism. Let $V(X)$ be a volume of a figure $X$ and $B(X)$ be a base area of a prism $X$. We already know that: $$V(ANMA_1N_1M_1)=V(NBCMN_1B_1C_1N_1)$$ from this it follows that: $$h \cdot B(ANMA_1N_1M_1)=h \cdot B(NBCMN_1B_1C_1M_1)$$ dividing by $h$ on both sides we get, that $B(ANMA_1N_1M_1)=B(NBCMN_1B_1C_1M_1)$, which means that $MN$ has the desired property. So any line that passes through the centroid of a triangle divides it into two parts of equal area.

it's rather that $m=V\cdot d$

Your claim is false: if you consider a line through the centroid, parallel to a side of the triangle, then one of the two pieces is a triangle similar to the original triangle, with similarity ratio $2/3$. Hence its area is $4/9$ of the area of the original triangle.

Oh yes, you are right. I didn't even think about it.

@Dmitro, your claim is true iff the line also pass through one vertex in addition to centroid. In this case the line is the median of triangle and bisects its area.


Two particular cases are when:
1- Drawing the nedian.
2- Drawing line EF parallel with base BC, if you do not want the line passes through a vertex. In this case the parallel line EF makes triangle  AEF  similar to ABC. The ratio of areas is equal to the square of ratio of bases:
$$\frac{S_{AEF}}{S_{ABC}}=\frac{x^2}{a^2}$$
$S_{AEF}-\frac 12 S_{ABC}$
These two relations give:
$x=\frac{a\sqrt 2}2$
It becomes a bit complicated if you went EF not parallel with BC or passes through the centroid.
